# On element hover div opens

Tags: jquery

Here's an example :

```
    $("div").hover(function() {
    //code
    });
```

What if I want to do this. :

```
$("div", "anotherdiv").hover(function() {
//code
});
```

Is it possible? First of all let me explain why I want to do this... On hovering over 1st div the second div actually opens up.. I have written that code..but I want to keep the second div still open on hovering over the second div as well.. My main aim is to keep the second div open on hovering over the first div and on hovering over the second div as well..

Comment: Can you show the HTML

Comment: you can use a variable to check if the second div is open

Comment: the selector would be `$("div, anotherdiv")`

Comment: As the first selector selects all DIV elements in the document, why would you need to add another DIV ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. but you need to specify to which div you're referring : by `Id` (`#thingy`)or by Class (`.thingy`).

```
$("div,#anotherdiv").hover(function() {
//code
});
```

what weve done here is for all div elements (`div`) and for a specific div which has id of `anotherDiv`. ( this example is meaningless cuz we apply the hover to all div at first place.

Comment: no no I will surely give ids. I did not mention that because I thought it is quite obvious that it wont work without it..anyway thanks.